# assign object array to class attribute vba

Tags: vb6

I have maintain array of class objects using another class member variable. I was unable to set the object array to the class variable. Able to call the setter method but gives error "can't assign a array"

```
Class module AA

private c as integer
private d as integer

Class module B
private a(50) as AA

public sub setA(byref a1() as AA)
    a = a1        ' this assignment not work.
end sub

public function getA() as AA()
    getA = a              ' this work
end function

Module main

dim tags() as A
dim tag as A
with B
    Redim preserve tags(ubound(.getA()) ' get the class module b array and set the element as 50
    for i =0 to ubound(tags)
        if tags(i) is nothing then
            tag.setC(3)
            tag.setD(5)
            tags(i) = tag
        end if
    next i

    .setA tags ' call the setter method but gives error can't assign a array

end with
```

Comment: Have you tried: Set a = a1   ?

Comment: wait a sec ill try. Gives error Can't assign to array

Comment: looks like byref is spelled wrong.  You have byfef.

Comment: G Mastros its my mistake happened when i am asking this question. But in my code its wrote as ByRef. I edited it now. thx

Comment: in SetA do `ReDim PReserve` on A then assign each element from A1

Comment: If I add "ReDim Preserve a" gives me syntax error.

Comment: ...and instead of `private a(50) as AA` in the class use `Dim a(50) as AA`

Comment: @Plutonix there is no difference between Dim and Private in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign to an array if you declare the size of the array.  Try something like this:

```
Class module B
private a() as AA

public sub setA(byref a1() as AA)
    a = a1        ' this should work now.
end sub

public function getA() as AA()
    getA = a              ' this work
end function

public sub class_initialize
    redim a(50)
end sub
```